# How to fix the error is not assignable to InstrinsicAttributes in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to add a prop to a reusable component using react and typescript and doing so gives me an error.

Type marginleft:number is not assignable to type Intrinsic attributes.

What i am trying to do?

i have a reusable components namely Text and Count.

i use Text component within the Count component and the code is like below,

```
function Parent() {
    render = () => {
        return (
            <Count marginleft={8}/> //this is where i get the error
        )
     }
 }

 interface Props {
     marginleft?: number;
 }
 function Count = () => {
     render = () => {
         return (
             <Wrapper>
                 <Text color="red"/>
             </Wrapper>
        )
    }
}
const Wrapper = styled.div<Props>`
    margin-left: ${props => props.marginleft + 'px' || 0};
`;


interface Props {
    color?: string;
}

const Text = styled.span<Props>`
    line-height: ${props => props.lineh || 4.5};
`;
```

I am not sure why i am getting this error. I want to add marginleft prop to Count component such that i can place it and adjust it anywhere in the application.

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to tidy up your code. I can't run and check whether it is working but i am hoping it will be helpful to you. You can't use `render` inside a functional component and most of the time you won't need to use a return statement.

```
interface IWrapperProps {
  marginleft: number;
}

interface ITextProps {
  color: string;
}

const Wrapper = styled.div<IWrapperProps>`
  margin-left: ${(props) => props.marginleft + "px" || 0};
`;

const Text = styled.span<ITextProps>`
  line-height: ${(props) => props.lineh || 4.5};
`;

const Count = ({ marginleft }) => (
  <Wrapper marginleft={marginleft}>
    <Text color="red" />
  </Wrapper>
);

const Parent = () => <Count marginleft={8} />;
```